# Вложенность блоков в БЭМ

Tags: css, вёрстка, бэм

К примеру, есть такой код (кстати, согласно БЭМ, он верен?):

```
<div class="article">
    <article class="article__item item">
        <img src="" alt="" class="item__img">
        <div class="item__description">
            Some text
        </div>
        <a href="" class="item__button button">
            <i class="button__icon"></i>
            <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
        </a>
    </article>
</div>
```

scss код верстки, выглядел бы примерно так:

```
.article {
  &__item { ... }
}

.item {
  &__img { ... }
  &__description { ... }
  &__button { ... }
}

.button {
  &__icon { ... }
  &__text { ... }
}
```

Согласно идеологии БЭМ, запрещено создавать блоки блоков, т.е. писать так: `class="article__item__description"` или `class="article__item__button"`.

Вместо этого, используются классы для перехода от одного блока к другому, т.е. `class="article__item item"`.

Но что, если в другом месте страницы мне понадобится применить класс `item`, например, добавится такой код:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item item">
        <a href="" class="item__button button">
            <i class="button__icon button__icon_social_fb"></i>
            <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item item">
        <a href="" class="item__button button">
            <i class="button__icon button__icon_social_vk"></i>
            <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item item">
        <a href="" class="item__button button">
            <i class="button__icon button__icon_social_ok"></i>
            <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

и согласно шаблону, классы `item` и `button` должны выглядеть иначе, чем в примере выше, т.е. есть необходимость классы этих блоков переопределить. Как БЭМ предлагает решить такую ситуацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/bem/bem-forum-content-ru/issues/104

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu__item">
    <a href="" class="menu__button">
        <i class="menu__icon menu__icon_social_fb"></i>
        <span class="menu__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
    <a href="" class="menu__button">
        <i class="menu__icon menu__icon_social_vk"></i>
        <span class="menu__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menu__item">
    <a href="" class="menu__button">
        <i class="menu__icon menu__icon_social_ok"></i>
        <span class="menu__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

```
.article {
    &__item { ... }
    &__img { ... }
    &__button { ... }
    &__icon { ... }
    &__text { ... }
}

.menu {
    &__item { ... }
    &__icon {
        &_social_fb { ... }
        &_social_vk { ... }
        &_social_ok { ... }
    }
    &__button { ... }
    &__text { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Модификатор. В вашем случае это могут быть `item_menu` и `item_article`. Мне кажется у вас ошибка в том, что вы задаете одновременно блок и элемент, например, `class="article__item item"`. `item` это блок, `article__item` это элемент.
Я бы сделал `item item_article` и `item item_menu`, в `item` было бы общее между `item_article` и `item_menu`.

```
<div class="article">
  <article class="item item_article">
    <img src="" alt="" class="item__img">
    <div class="item__description">
        Some text
    </div>
    <a href="" class="button button_item">
        <i class="button__icon"></i>
        <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
  </article>
</div>

<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item item_menu">
    <a href="" class="button button_item">
        <i class="button__icon button__icon_social_fb"></i>
        <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item item_menu">
    <a href="" class="button button_item">
        <i class="button__icon button__icon_social_vk"></i>
        <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="item item_menu">
    <a href="" class="button button_item">
        <i class="button__icon button__icon_social_ok"></i>
        <span class="button__text">Some text</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

.item {
  &_article { ... }
  &_menu { ... }
  &__img { ... }
  &__description { ... }
  &__button { ... }
}

.button {
  &_item { ... }
  &__icon { ... }
  &__text { ... }
}
```